# how to create class of findViewById?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, class, variables, findviewbyid

I am a beginner ,https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8z9T.jpgin the android studio whenever I try to use findViewById.It shows an error and they ask me to create its variable but I don't know how to create it . Please tell me, I am stuck here.

Comment: Look carefully at your brackets. You defined that function outside of your activity class. It needs to be inside. Also, for future questions here, please don’t post pictures of code. Paste the text of your code in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just created a function outside of your **MainActivity**. You have to create it inside of your activity. According to your screenshot, you just try to create a **Top-level Function** not a **Function** because it's outside of your activity. When you need to create a **Function** you have to create that inside your activity. Keep your eyes on **Curley Brackets** ***{}***.

See the explanation to understand.

- **In your screenshot**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
} /* Your activity end's on here*/

private fun addNickName(view: View) {
    // Your instance
    // val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nickName_edit)
}
```

- **So the answer is**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    private fun addNickName(view: View) {
        // Your instance
        // val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nickName_edit)
    }
} /* Your activity end's on here*/
```

**Hope you understand!. *Thank you***

Comment: A function defined outside a class is not another class. It's just a top-level function.